# hdparm -I does not work for logical volumes; HDIO_DRIVE_CMD(identify) failed: Invalid exchange

Tags: linux, ssd, hdparm

Does anyone know if hdparm works for logical volumes?

```
[root@qlnx053 home]# pvdisplay
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sdb1
  VG Name               vg01_sas
  PV Size               835.39 GiB / not usable 19.00 MiB
  Allocatable           yes (but full)
  PE Size               128.00 MiB
  Total PE              6683
  Free PE               0
  Allocated PE          6683
  PV UUID               lDZCKQ-twdC-zfj0-AG4W-yjnV-JjfV-WhHjQu

  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sda2
  VG Name               vg00_ssd
  PV Size               236.49 GiB / not usable 49.00 MiB
  Allocatable           yes (but full)
  PE Size               64.00 MiB
  Total PE              3783
  Free PE               0
  Allocated PE          3783
  PV UUID               UVq6D3-u1Dd-8ty9-HQ7g-9UMS-haJg-Le1Vro

[root@qlnx053 home]# sudo hdparm -I /dev/sda2

/dev/sda2:
 HDIO_DRIVE_CMD(identify) failed: Invalid exchange
[root@qlnx053 home]#
```

Answer (score 1):

Most actions with hdparm require root privileges. Also, the command takes a *drive* for the device parameter, not a *partition* as in your example. Try this:

```
hdparm -I /dev/sda
```

Comment: It still does not work. Same error message. Am I running into security issues? I do have sudo accesss

Comment: Perhaps your disk does not support the IDENTIFY command. I notice from your VG name that it might be an SAS disk. hdparm is for IDE and SATA.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense. That box has SAS in it as well as SSD. I am not sure exactly how they are mounted. I do not have access to the physical server.